# Hudson log going into stderr and also not rolling over

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, hudson

Having a bizarre, awkward issue where

**a)** the Hudson operational log is going into the tomcat7-stderr.xdatex.log

**b)** it's not rolling over, meaning a cron job to clean the logs when they get too big, doesn't work

Been trying to use newer jars, different log4j.properties setups, changing the settings in tomcat7w, all to no avail. Here's my setup:

**Tomcat7w:**

```
Level: Info
Log Path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs
Log Prefix: tomcat_logging
Redirect Stdout: auto
Redirect Stderror: auto
Java Options:-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
-Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\log4j.properties
```

**In tomcat 7.0/conf/**

```
logging.properties has been renamed to logging.properties.off to disable it
```

**In tomcat 7.0/lib/**

```
log4j.jar, tomcat-juli.jar (from extras) and tomcat-juli-adapters.jar are present, as is log4j.properties
```

My log4j.properties file:
http://pastebin.com/7gk4hbMy

And a slice of stderr:
http://pastebin.com/C0UtY09x

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Are you using tomcat log4j.properties for your hudson ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.
The Husdon in question is running on a Tomcat that's using log4j, yes.

Answer (score 0):

All the logs are written into

```
{catalina.base}
```

Thats why all logs generated in the tomcat logs

Comment: Sure, but I'm more wondering why it goes into stderr and why it doesn't roll over.

Comment: @GavinFitzgerald what you mean ?

Comment: The stderr.log file for this tomcat became where all the hudson messages go, errors or not. The file also isn't rolling over, so the single stderr.log file becomes huge.